# Google place page is not shown in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to show

http://www.google.co.jp/m/place#ipd:mode=home

website thru WebView in Android emulator but I am not seeing the web
site and seeing only blank space under the place tag of the page.

I am able to see other sites like www.google.com.

Do I need to enable more settings for the google place page?

Permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Code

```
WebView view= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
View.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
View.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
View.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
View.loadUrl(" http://www.google.co.jp/m/place#ipd:mode=home");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

on the setting object. That fixed the problem for me.